# OnTouch Event not working , because User feedback is not supported

Tags: android, touch-event

every time this function is called I get an error.

```
  @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        int x=  (int)event.getX();
        int y = (int)event.getY();



        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

ERROR SEEN IN CONSOLE :

```
 W/ApsUserFeedback: APS: User feedback is not supported
    E/ApsLdfGameIdentify: binder error
    E/Hwaps: no data in database of APSAPPINFO
```

Can you please help me ? 
What does this error mean ?
[This is the error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3Xsi.png)